# Entity types after upgrading Magento from 1.5.1.0 to 1.7.0.0

Tags: php, magento

I’ve done upgrade of magento from version 1.5.1.0 to 1.7.0, over svn, by using, at most, instructions from [this article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/174/changing_and_customizing_magento_code#upgrading_to_a_newer_version). After few tweaks, site was upgraded, and seems to work well ie. no error has been noticed after short period of user testing.

But I am in doubt about new entity types that are exists in fresh installation of 1.7 (I think that most of them are introduced in 1.6.x versions), and does not exists in my upgrade.

Here is the list of those entity types that are exists in fresh installation of 1.7 version and does not exists in my upgraded version:

```
'creditmemo_comment'
'creditmemo_item'
'customer_payment'
'invoice_comment'
'invoice_item'
'invoice_shipment'
'order_address'
'order_item'
'order_payment'
'order_status'
'order_status_history'
'quote'
'quote_address'
'quote_address_item'
'quote_address_rate'
'quote_item'
'quote_payment'
'shipment_comment'
'shipment_item'
'shipment_track'
```

I want to ask if anyone else has this issue, and if anyone has solution for this? 
I am in doubt about this because, even site seems to work fine, i’m afraid that this difference in entity types could couse some error, later, on production.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to place a test order?

Comment: Yes I have. It seems to work fine, order mail has been sent, order has been registered in admin part and customer have order in it's profile page.

Comment: Does anyone else has successfully done upgrade from 1.5 to 1.7, I'm wondering if you have similar case with entity types.